# Connected USB device shows offline on Android Studio

Tags: android, usb, android-studio-2.3

Here's the problem, I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3 and executing programs on my Android Lenovo K5 plus, last time when the apk request arrived on my phone I checked on "always allow this computer" and hit ok, after that my connected device is displayed as offline on Virtual Device dialogbox.

I tried using different USB cable,
Different USB port (PC)
And revoking USB authorization from Developer options

Nothing helped, how can I reset/clean authorized devices on my phone or Android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In studio terminal fire following commands,

[image]

```
adb kill-server
```

after doing it fire this

```
adb start-server
```

Now re-connect your device.